How to control the `trainer.global_step` in pytorch lightning?
In pytorch lightning, the trainer will increase the global_step according to how many times xxx_optimizer.step() was executed when self.automatic_optimization = False.
However, I have two different optimizers in a single training step, which means self.trainer.global_step will be doubled.
That's annoying because the self.trainer.global_step will always be doubled when I enable the second optimizer, which makes my checkpoints callbacks run in a wrong way. They will misalign with other checkpoints that from experiments without second optimizer.
Is there any simple way I can solve this problem?
Stress: I am trying to control the global_step to make sure my Checkpoint Callback works correctly. (Because I am not sure wether other things will be wrong as well if I only modify the callback.)
I try to overwrite the self.trainer.global_step, but I found that it's a getter function and can't be modified.
